# Automatically clear notification from tray using programming (not working)

Tags: java, android

I want to clear the notification tray programmatically. I am using a service and I want to do that ondestroy method:

```
    protected void dismissProgressNotification() {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.cancel(PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

   `  @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      uploadTask.cancel();
      dismissProgressNotification()`
```

Here is my code but it did not work when I stop the service.

Comment: What happens in practice? Do you get an error message? 'It did not work' is not something anyone can help you debug. And please proof-read your questions before submitting them.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Try to use the application context, also you can test canceling all the the notifications

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Check the docs here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)